# How to sort RecyclerView headers and items by Date

Tags: android, sql, sorting, android-recyclerview

I cannot sort the `RecyclerView` in descending `order by date`. There are `headers` and `items`. I can only sort `items`, but no `headers`.

I tried to sort the `SQL Database` in descending order `(" DESC")`, but not successful.

[image]

```
private static final String EVENTS_CREATE_TABLE =
        "create table "
                + EVENTS.TABLE + " ("
                + EVENTS.EVENTS_ID + " integer primary key, "
                + EVENTS.COL_TITLE + " text, "
                + EVENTS.COL_DATE + " long" + ");";
```

``

```
public List<EventModel> getAllEvents() {
    List<EventModel> eventModelList = new ArrayList<>();

    openToRead();
    String orderBy = DBHelper.EVENTS.COL_DATE + " DESC";

    Cursor cursor = database.query(DBHelper.EVENTS.TABLE, 
    null, null, null, null, null, orderBy);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.EVENTS.COL_TITLE));
            long date = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.EVENTS.COL_DATE));

            EventModel eventModel = new EventModel(title, date);
            eventModelList.add(eventModel);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();

    return eventModelList;
}
```

There is my `fragment`:

```
    private void getList() {

         List<ListEvent> items = new ArrayList<>();

         Map<Long, List<EventModel>> events = toMap(loadEvents());

         for (long date : events.keySet()) {
            HeaderEvent header = new HeaderEvent(date);
            items.add(header);
            for (EventModel eventModel : events.get(date)) {
                EventItem item = new EventItem(itemModel);
                items.add(item);
            }
        }
        adapterEvent = new EventRVAdapter(getContext(), items);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapterEvent);

    }

    private List<EventModel> loadEvents() {
        List<EventModel> events = new ArrayList<>(mDBAdapter.getAllEvents());

        return events;
    }

    private Map<Long, List<EventModel>> toMap(List<EventModel> events) {
        Map<Long, List<EventModel>> map = new TreeMap<>();
        for (EventModel eventModel : events) {
            List<EventModel> value = map.get(eventModel.getDate());
            if (value == null) {
                value = new ArrayList<>();
                map.put(eventModel.getDate(), value);
            }

            value.add(eventModel);
        }
        return map;
    }
```

This is `ListEvent` class:

```
    public abstract class ListEvent {

        public static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0;
        public static final int TYPE_ITEM = 1;

        abstract public int getType();
    }
```

This is `EventItem.class`

```
    public class EventItem extends ListEvent{

        private EventModel eventModel;

        public EventItem(EventModel eventModel) {
            this.eventModel = eventModel;
        }

        public EventModel getEventModel() {
            return eventModel;
        }

        @Override
        public int getType() {
            return TYPE_ITEM;
        }
    }
```

This is `HeaderEvent` class:

```
    public class HeaderEvent extends ListEvent {

         private long date;

         public HeaderEvent(long date) {
              this.date = date;
         }

         public long getDate() {
              return date;
         }

         @Override
         public int getType() {
             return TYPE_HEADER;
         }
    }
```

This is my Model - `EventModel` class:

```
    public class EventModel {
        private String title;
        private long date;

        public EventModel(String title, long date) {
            this.title = title;
            this.date = date;
        }

        public String getTitle(){
            return title;
        }

        public long getDate(){
            return date;
        }
    }
```

And my `RecyclerView` adapter:

```
public class EventRVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private List<ListEvent> items;

public EventRVAdapter(List<ListEvent> items) {
    this.items = items;
}

public class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView tvName, tvDate;

    public ItemViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tvName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        tvDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
    }
}

public class HeaderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView tvHeaderDate;

    public HeaderViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tvHeaderDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvHeader);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    switch (viewType) {
        case ListEvent.TYPE_HEADER: {
            View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_header, parent, false);
            return new HeaderViewHolder(itemView);
        }
        case ListEvent.TYPE_ITEM: {
            View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, parent, false);
            return new ItemViewHolder(itemView);
        }
        default:
            throw new IllegalStateException("unsupported item type");
    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    int viewType = getItemViewType(position);

    switch (viewType) {
        case ListEvent.TYPE_HEADER: {
            HeaderEvent header = (HeaderEvent) items.get(position);
            HeaderViewHolder headerHolder = (HeaderViewHolder) holder;

            headerHolder.tvHeaderDate.setText(Utils.getDayAndTime(header.getDate()));
            break;
        }
        case ListEvent.TYPE_ITEM: {
            EventItem event = (EventItem) items.get(position);
            ItemViewHolder itemHolder = (ItemViewHolder) holder;

            itemHolder.tvName.setText(event.getEventModel().getTitle());
            itemHolder.tvDate.setText(Utils.getDateWithoutTime(event.getEventModel().getDate()));

            break;
        }
        default:
            throw new IllegalStateException("unsupported item type");
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return items.get(position).getType();
}
```

}

Could you help me to find solution or give advice?

Comment: Column data type? Show us the result set ordered as required - as formatted text (no images.)

Comment: @jarlh Column COL_DATE - long. COL_TITLE - text. I updated the content of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`keySet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#keySet()) method documentation claims:

> The set's iterator returns the keys in ascending order.

And this is just the behaviour you have.

There is no need to use `Map` to prepare list of items with headers. It's better to  just iterate the sorted list of events and store last date to compare to at the next step. Here is a code sample:

```
List<EventModel> events = loadEvents();
List<ListEvent> items = new ArrayList<>();
long date = -1L;
for (EventModel event : events) {
    if (event.getDate() != date) {
        date = event.getDate();
        items.add(new HeaderEvent(date));
    }
    items.add(new EventItem(event));
}
```

Comment: You are just amazing! Indeed, keySet() returns the keys in ascending order. Could you give me simple example about your advice?